# Continuity of a derivate function

Tags: continuity

Is there exists a continuous function whose derivate function is NOT continuous?
To be more specific, $f$ is  continuous while $f'$ isn't.
I'm just looking for a drawable example for a project.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the absolute value function?
$$
f(x) = |x|
$$

Comment: *continuous*, not *continues*.

Comment: @ Matti: the absolut value function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @MattiP.: undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Example: $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=0.$

$f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$,

$f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$,

$f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: thank you so much, it seems understandable. Sorry but can you think of any other example? And basically what gives the function that adjective?